# How to programming Xor calculator hex base 16 in java Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, xor

How to program Xor calculator for hexadecimal (base 16) in Java like in the screenshot shown below? The first input is the key and the second input is the string, the third one is the output. Actually I tried a lot of scripts and I googled the issue but the result is not coming true like in this calculators. Please Help. 
[Online Xor Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn3Y0.png)
and
[Windows programmer mode calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YncKF.png)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView sharecode = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sharecode);
    final TextView finalcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfinalcode);
    final Button calculatcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculatcode);
    final EditText tbpin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPin);
    final EditText tbappcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etappcode);
    tbappcode.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});


    sharecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (finalcode.getText().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no code to share it!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Application Code is:" + finalcode.toString());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }

        }
    });

    calculatcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         if (tbpin.getText().toString().equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter PIN Code!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } else if (tbappcode.getText().toString().equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Last part of Appcode Code!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } else {

              String a = tbappcode.getText().toString();
              String b = tbpin.getText().toString();

             int[] encrypted = encrypt(a, b);
              for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++)

              finalcode.setText(decrypt(encrypted, b));

                  }

               }
           }
    );

}

private static int[] encrypt(String str, String key) {
    int[] output = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int o = (Integer.valueOf(str.charAt(i)) ^ Integer.valueOf(key.charAt(i % (key.length() - 1)))) + '0';
        output[i] = o;
    }
    return output;
}

private static String decrypt(int[] input, String key) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output += (char) ((input[i] - 48) ^ (int) key.charAt(i % (key.length() - 1)));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and show what output you are getting. "Doesn't work" isn't a good enough explanation of what's happening!

Comment: The result should be like in images attached.

Comment: Everything is working without error exception, But the result calculation is incorrect.  My String is 316ab2cb and the key is 19421942 the result should be 2828ab89.  with my code I am getting 316ab2cb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your String for int or long numbers.
When we have 16base number we have to change this number to 2base.
For example(In your picture):
Last number in first input is 2, in second input last number is b.

2 in binary - 0010

b in binary - 1011

Result of Xor(if firstInput=!secondInput) 1001 and this is 9. Like in picture.

So you have to split your String, get one digit, convert this to 16base number, do this with second string and use XOR binary operator ^.

```
int[] firstInput ={1,9,4,2,1,9,4,2};
int[] secondInput ={3,1,6,a,b,2,c,b};
int[] output = new int[8];
for(i=0;i<firstInput.length();i++){
     output[i]=firstInput[i]^secondInput[i];
}
```

This is only sample of the code, very simple and partial.
Operation for the XoR is ^ operator.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look below on computation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int i = 0x316AB2CB;
    int j = 0x19421942;

    int res = i^j;
    System.out.printf("Hex: %x\n", res);
    System.out.printf("Octal: %o\n", res);
    System.out.printf("Decimal: %d\n", res);
}
```

You may take a look at [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) as you may not always be interested to print the results.